# Pandas groupby and then find max value per group in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[This is not the whole dataset, just .head(10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvGFH.png)

I want a dataframe with 3 columns: groupby user_id

1. ’user_id’
2. The ‘product_id’ that is most ordered per ‘user_id’ (max in ‘uxp_total_bought' per ‘user_id’)
3. How many times it was bought (‘uxp_total_bought’)

[What I expect:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mavp4.png)

Comment: What we expect: copy-paste-able example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is gonna work.

```
test = your_dataset.groupby('product_id')['uxp_total_bought'].max()
test = test.reset_index()
test = your_dataset.loc[uxp.groupby("user_id")["uxp_total_bought"].idxmax()]
del test["uxp_total_bought"]
test.rename(columns = {"product_id":"favourite_product_id"}, inplace = True)
```